# Unity dash as well as Terminal is not coming

Tags: gnome-terminal, unity-dash, 14.10

I was browsing through `google chrome` before I shutting down my system. I had to go out urgent for some work, since I directly clicked on shutdown option. then it was a proper shutdown.
 When I returned back after 2-3 hours, I started my laptop again, then it is just showing desktop with the icons available on it. I have `gedit`, `chrome`, and a `folder` on my desktop.
    So I'm able to open those applications. Even On pressing `super` key it is not opening Unity `dash`, neither a terminal. I can just open a folder and can go to any directory.

Can anyone help me,

- What I should do to open a terminal or unity dash?
- Is there any executable available for `gnome-terminal`, so that I will go there   to launch it.

Please help, I can't do anything.

**Note** : Here is the `dmesg` [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9174380/). http://paste.ubuntu.com/9174380/

Comment: Did you tried restarting?

Comment: @remyseroos:-Yes of course! I tried for 3 times.

Comment: Switch to a VT (cntrl+alt+F1), login and enter the command dmesg. Please post the output from the command here or on some pastebin site and post the link.

Comment: @remyseroos :- Thanks, I tried it, there is something very long output. almost 969 lines. Here is the link for pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/9174380/

Comment: at paste.ubuntu.com. Then just post the URL.

Comment: @remyseroos :- Yeah, pasted please check.

Comment: @remyseroos- Any idea please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18894/discussion-between-remyseroos-and-trex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug (see [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1292396))

The current work-around is:

From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install unity
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

This will reinstall unity and reset the config.

If that doesn't works then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
rm -f /home/user/.config/dconf/user
```

but be aware that this solution will install **all** of the packages from ubuntu-desktop (including things like gedit, sound utility, archive managers etc.)

Comment: Really, Thank you very much. Second solution worked well.